# Multiple id in a while loop in order to display bootstrap popover

Tags: javascript, popover

I have multiple bootstrap popovers in a while loop but they have the same id, so i have some problems about the display. Can you tell me on can I increment id ?

```
<?php while ($ligne = $displayClient->fetch()){ ?>
    <tr>
        <th><?php echo $ligne['client_id']; ?></th>
        <th><?php echo $ligne['client_type']; ?></th>
        <th><?php echo func_date_us_vers_francais($ligne['client_dateAdded']); ?></th>
        <th><?php echo $ligne['client_name']; ?></th>
        <th><?php echo $ligne['client_city']; ?></th>
        <th><?php echo $ligne['client_cp']; ?></th>
        <th><?php echo $ligne['client_adresse']; ?></th>
        <th><?php echo $ligne['client_phone']; ?></th>
        <th><?php if($ligne['client_mail'] == ''){echo '';}else{ ?> <a href="mailto:<?php echo $ligne["client_mail"]; ?>"><i class="fa fa-envelope fa-2x"></i></a> <?php } ?></th>
        <th>
            <script type="text/javascript">
            $('#cc').popover({

            });</script>
            <button type="button" id="cc" class="btn btn-default" data-html="true" data-delay="100" data-placement="left" data-toggle="popover" title="Actions" data-content='<a href="?page=clientUpdate.php&id=echo $ligne["client_id"]"><button type="submit" name="btn_update_client" id="btn_update_client" class="btn btn-default btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-pencil fa-2x"></i></button></a><button type="button" name="btn_delete_client" id="btn_delete_client" value="$ligne["client_id"]" onclick="form_confirm();" class="btn btn-default btn-danger"><i class="fa fa-times fa-2x"></i></button>'><i class="fa fa-cog fa-2x"></i></button>
        </th>
    </tr>
    <?php } ?>
```

Comment: Maybe change the selector to: `$('[data-toggle]').popover();` after you print all the buttons (output script after while loop)?

Comment: Are you sure you need an ID? Use a class instead.

Comment: this is the same thing with a class

Comment: i need to increment the id i think

Comment: nobody got an idea ?